# Getting values from database on select dropdown in textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, hibernate

Please answer the below question

I want to get the details from database on select of the option and display the values of the related select option accordingly

```
 <table border="1" class="form" id="dataTable">
            <tbody>
                <tr class="vd_bg-green vd_white" id='row_0'>
                    <td><input name="chk" type="checkbox"></td>
                    <td><select id="product_name" name="product_name" oninput=
                    "calculate('row_0')" required="" style="width: 180px; color: black">
                    <option>//options from database</option>
                    </select></td>
                    <td><input id="description" maxlength="70" name="description" oninput=
                    "calculate('row_0')" required="" style="width: 260px; color: black" type=
                    "text"></td>
                    <td><input id="price" name="price" oninput="calculate('row_0')" required=""
                    style="width: 80px; color: black" type="text"></td>
                    <td><input id="quantity" name="quantity" oninput="calculate('row_0')"
                    required="" style="width: 40px; color: black" type="text"></td>
                    <td><input id="disc_rate" name="disc_rate" oninput="calculate('row_0')"
                    required="" style="width: 40px; color: black" type="text"></td>
                    <td><input id="total_pro" name="total_pro" onchange="calculate('row_0')"
                    readonly="readonly" style="width: 80px; color: black" type="text"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: have you tried anything from your  side? please share some code here.

Comment: please share you code here that you have tried so far

Comment: how do i share i am new to stackoverflow

Comment: please use edit link below your post and add your code so that we can help you better. Please check [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Can you share some code in jsp and ajax??

Answer (score 0):

You can start learning ajax and server side scripting. Create a server side code. Pass the selected value to it by ajax. Get the results from the database. Show the result in the text box.

Comment: But the rows here are created dynamically and i need to do the calculations in it

Comment: @optimus you can do thw calculations in the server side. Sorry I can't. You mat wanna learn about these topics: PHP, AJAX, SQL, jQuery.ajax, JS